# Problem on a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $f_n:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ be defined as follows:
>
> For $n=2^k+p$ where $0\leq p<2^k$
>
> $f_n(t)$=\begin{cases} 1& \text{if}&t\in [\frac{p}{2^k},\frac{p+1}{2^k})\\
>  0&&\text{otherwise} \end{cases}
>
> Find $\lim \sup f_n(t).$

Comment: Is this a total lack of context or what?

Answer (score 2):

Fix an $x$. What values do you see $f_n(x)$ taking? We see $0$ when $x$ is not in that interval and $1$ when it is. How often? Well, does intervals, when $n$ moves, they shrink and they circle all over the interval $[0,1]$ over and over again. Therefore you see the $1$ and the $0$ infinitely many times.

The sequence of values we see is $0$ and $1$ in some pattern that repeats them infinitely many times. What is the $\limsup$ of that?